# Rest Web service in JAVA

Tags: java, web-services, rest

What is the most common and standardized way to create a ReST Java Web service ?
For now, I just use a Perl program to invoke my Java application but I think it's not the most efficient way.

Comment: Maybe a little googling will help ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) for creating RESTful webservices as it is officially part of java EE 6 specification, previously JAX-RPC was used which has now been replaced by JAX-RS, wikipedia states:

> JAX-RS: Java API for RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS) is a Java programming language API that provides support in creating web services according to the Representational State Transfer (REST) architectural pattern.[1] JAX-RS uses annotations, introduced in Java SE 5, to simplify the development and deployment of web service clients and endpoints.
>   From version 1.1 on, JAX-RS is an official part of Java EE 6